# WordPress - Splitting a single page into multiple urls that can be indexed by Google

Tags: wordpress, seo

I want to know if it is possible to split a single page into several unique pages so that Google sees them as a separate page and indexes them as such.

As an example there would be a landing page called 'Creative'.

Within this page are different sections, currently just divs with a unique id e.g. branding, packaging.

As you scroll to those sections, I would like the url to go from:

- www.site/creative/

TO

- www.site/creative/branding

TO

- www.site/creative/packaging

There is no lazy loading taking place.  The divs are all displayed upon the page loading.

The reason behind doing this is that there is not enough content to warrant the additional pages but the SEO value of these different urls is required.

Thanks for your time and help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create parent pages. But when you don't get enough content and you split your content into subpages you will create double-content.

You can try to spin your content in unique new content to fill the deep pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't relate to what I am trying to do.  It is a single page with multiple divs which somehow need to create a new url per div and be indexed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Certainly index your content for sub-pages, if you have unique content for both the branding and packaging URLs. And also try to create long content for the pages which describe in depth about service, so GoogleBot will be easily cached your page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the question states that these are not sub pages.  They are a bunch of separate divs within a single page.

Answer (score 0):

If you uses a cms for web creation and did parallex website, it'll automatically index the various sections of your website into different pages for indexing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is no lazy load or parallax scrolling taking place.  It is just a bunch of separate divs on a single page.